# Does anisotropic stress cancel at the center by symmetry?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, elasticity

Let's define :

$$ \sigma_{ij}=\tilde{\sigma_{ij}} - P \delta_{ij} $$
with $\sigma$ the stress tensor, $P$ the pressure and $\tilde{\sigma}$ the anisotropic stress tensor.

The balance of force imposes : $$ \partial_{i}\tilde{\sigma}_{ij} - \partial_jP=0 $$.

My question is do anisotropic stresses cancel at the center because of the symmetries. For example, for a fluid in spherical coordinates and radial symmetry we have :

$$ \tilde{\sigma}_{rr}\sim\tilde{\sigma}_{\theta\theta}\sim \tilde{\sigma}_{\phi\phi} \sim \partial_rv-v/r$$

Do we have at the center of the sphere :  $\partial_rv-v/r=0$ ?

I'm asking the question because of some intuition that anisotropic stresses have some directions, and that's not consistant with the center of symmetry, I mean we will have a singularity at the center. Is it right ? 
And if not does anisotropic stress resect certain conditions at the center ?

Comment: What is the "constraints tensor"?

Comment: Sorry I used the French word by mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a problem with spherical symmetry the balance of forces is given by

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_{rr}}{\partial r} + \frac{2}{r}[\sigma_{rr} - \sigma_{\phi\phi}] + f_r = 0\, ,$$

when $\sigma_{\phi\phi} = \sigma_{\theta\theta}$ have been used.

We also have the following (non-trivial) deformation components

\begin{align}
&\epsilon_{rr} =\frac{\mathrm{d} u_r}{\mathrm{d} r}\, \\
&\epsilon_{\phi\phi} = \epsilon_{\theta\theta} =\frac{ u_r}{r}\, .
\end{align}

This leads to the following

$$
\sigma_{rr} = \frac{2 \lambda u_r}{r} + \left(\lambda + 2 \mu\right) \frac{d}{d r} u_r\, ,\\
\sigma_{\phi\phi} = \sigma_{\theta\theta} = \lambda \frac{d}{d r} u_r + \frac{\lambda u_r}{r} + \frac{\left(\lambda + 2 \mu\right) u_r}{r}\, .
$$

I suppose that what you call "anisotropic stress" is the deviatoric part of the stress tensor, i.e.,

$$\tilde{\sigma} = \frac{2}{3} \mu \left(\frac{d}{d r} u_r - \frac{u_r}{r}\right)
\begin{pmatrix} 2 &0 &0\\ 0 &-1 &0\\ 0 &0 &-1\end{pmatrix}\, .$$

And I don't see that clear what you suggest.

Comment: What if u = kr ?

Comment: @ChetMiller, in that case, the deviatoric would be zero everywhere. That case corresponds to a sphere with uniform pressure applied in the exterior.

Comment: I think you're writing the stress for an elastic solid and I wrote it for a fluid, don't you ?

Comment: @J.A, yes I wrote for an elastic solid. In your question it was never implied that you wanted it for a fluid (Newtonian?).

Comment: I wrote the stress in function of a velocity, so I had in mind more a fluid, but actually I think the answer should be the same. So my question is $\tilde{\sigma}(r=0)=0$ ? I mean does the anisotropy implies something concerning the anisotropic stress at the center ?